# Getting a/d converter example program to work in a C++ windows program

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2017, analog-digital-converter

I got the following example code for a C windows programm from the developer of my analog to digital converter and want to make it run as a windows c++ project in Visual Studio 2016.

As a beginner in C++, windows API and this universal library for the converter I'm overwhelmed with the troubleshooting right now. The plan was to learn by making the code work but right now it's really hard to find out where the problems are and there's not the time to learn everything from scratch (though I try next to it)

This is my setup: Windows 7 64bit, MS Visual Studio Community 2017, USB 1608fs plus a/d converter with its universal library

These are the errors I'm currently getting:

> - a value of type "HANDLE" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "HINSTANCE" (row 83)
> - a value of type "HGDIOBJ" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "HBRUSH"(row 86)
> - the argument of type "HANDLE" is incompatible with parameter type "HINSTANCE" (row 93)

Actions I took until now:

- creating a new empty win32 project in MS Visual Studio
- copying the example code
- copying the header file and the library from the converter into the same folder
- switching the character set from unicode to multibyte
- switching off the precompiled header
- include the missing headers from the precompiled header

Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>                    /* Compiler's include files's */
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cbw.h"                        /* Universal Library's include file */
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#define BOARD_NUM      0                /* Number of A/D board as defined with InstaCal */
#define ADRANGE        BIP5VOLTS        /* A/D voltage range */
#define TIMER_NUM      1                /* Windows timer used by this program */

HWND hWndMain;                          /* handle for main window */

LONG FAR PASCAL MainMessageHandler(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/************************************************************************
*
* Name:      WinMain
*
* Arguments: hInstance - the instance handle for the program
*            hPrevInstance - the class name of the application (not used)
*            CmndLine - command line was called with (not used)
*            CmndShow - indicates how to display window
*
* This is the entry point to the program. It gets called by Windows
* to start the program up.  This routine creates the main window,
* initializes a timer, and then falls into the main Windows Get
* message/Dispatch message loop.
*
************************************************************************/

int PASCAL
WinMain(HANDLE hInstance, HANDLE hPrevInstance, LPSTR CmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG       msg;                      /* MSG structure to pass to windows proc */
    WNDCLASS  wndclass;
    char      *AppName;                 /* Name for the window */

    cbErrHandling(PRINTALL, STOPALL);  /* Set library's error handling */

    CmdLine = NULL;                     /* Not used */
    AppName = "WINCDEMO";               /* The name of this application */
    if (!hPrevInstance)
    {
        wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wndclass.lpfnWndProc = MainMessageHandler;
        wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
        wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, AppName);
        wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wndclass.hbrBackground = GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
        wndclass.lpszMenuName = AppName;
        wndclass.lpszClassName = AppName;
        RegisterClass(&wndclass);
    }

    /* create application's Main window                                    */
    hWndMain = CreateWindow(AppName,                  /* Window class name          */
        "AIn Demo",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,           /* Use default X, Y            */
        CW_USEDEFAULT,           /* Use default X, Y            */
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE) * 12,   /* x - fit text     */
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZE) * 10,  /* y - fit text      */
        NULL,                    /* Parent window's handle      */
        NULL,                    /* Default to Class Menu       */
        hInstance,               /* Instance of window          */
        NULL);                   /* Create struct for WM_CREATE */


    if (hWndMain == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Could not create window in WinMain", NULL, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return (1);
    }

    ShowWindow(hWndMain, nCmdShow);     /* Display main window      */
    UpdateWindow(hWndMain);

    //    /* Start a 500ms timer to update display */
    if (!SetTimer(hWndMain, TIMER_NUM, 50, NULL))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Error starting Windows timer", NULL, MB_OK |
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return (1);
    }

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) /* Main message loop */
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnregisterClass(AppName, hInstance);
    return (msg.wParam);
}



/************************************************************************
*
* Name:      MainMessageHandler
*
* Arguments: hWnd - handle to the window
*            Message - message that needs to be handled
*            hParam - message parameter
*            lParam - message parameter
*
* This is the message dispatcher that gets called whenever Windows
* sends a message to this window.  WinMain started up a timer that
* sends a message every 1/2 sec.  When the message (WM_TIMER)is received
* by this routine, it reads the A/D.
* It also causes a screen update which will automatically generate a
* WM_PAINT message.  The WM_PAINT handler takes care of converting the
* raw A/D values to voltages and printing them in the Window.
*
************************************************************************/

LONG FAR PASCAL
MainMessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC        hDC;                     /* handle for the display device  */
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;                     /* holds PAINT information        */
    TEXTMETRIC tm;                      /* holds TEXT information         */

    static HRGN hRgn;                   /* Rectangle region Handles       */
    static int  CharWidth, CharHeight;
    static unsigned short DataVal;
    int        x, y;
    char       OutString[80], *str;
    float      Voltage;

    switch (Message)                    /* Windows Message Loop           */
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hDC = GetDC(hWndMain);      /* Get the device context for window */
        GetTextMetrics(hDC, &tm);   /* From context, get size of font */
        CharWidth = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
        CharHeight = tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading;
        ReleaseDC(hWndMain, hDC);
        hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, CharWidth * 30, CharHeight * 12);
        break;

    case WM_TIMER:                  /* All Timer Events Processed Here */
        InvalidateRgn(hWndMain, hRgn, FALSE);  /* Force screen update  */
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:                  /* Repaint client area of window */
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWndMain, &ps);
        x = CharWidth * 2;          /* Position cursor within window */
        y = CharHeight;             /* One line down and 2 chars in */
        str = "         A/D Info";  /* Print title */
        TextOut(hDC, x, y, str, strlen(str));

        y += CharHeight;            /* Print current index */
        cbAIn(BOARD_NUM, 0, ADRANGE, &DataVal);

        y += CharHeight * 2;            /* Print raw data value */
        sprintf(OutString, "Raw A/D value = %u    ", DataVal);
        TextOut(hDC, x, y, OutString, strlen(OutString));

        y += CharHeight;    /* Convert raw A/D to volts and print */
        cbToEngUnits(BOARD_NUM, ADRANGE, DataVal, &Voltage);
        sprintf(OutString, "Voltage = %.2f    ", Voltage);
        TextOut(hDC, x, y, OutString, strlen(OutString));

        SetTextAlign(hDC, TA_LEFT | TA_TOP);
        EndPaint(hWndMain, &ps);
        break;

    case WM_CLOSE:                      /* Close the window */
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        if (hWnd == hWndMain)
            PostQuitMessage(0);         /* Send message to Quit application */
        break;

    default:
        return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam));
    }
    return (0l);
}
```

Comment: Are we expected to guess, which lines of code cause the errors? Please see [ask] to learn, what a question should look like. Also, these are multiple errors. Please provide a [mcve] for each (decomposing the issue into separate questions). It's likely that all of those problems have already been asked and answered.

Comment: As an aside, if you don't want to learn, and just shut up the compiler, you could [disable STRICT type checking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383679.aspx). Totally not recommended, because now your compiler will let you write bugs it cannot discover, plus all those bugs it could have with STRICT type checking enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of randomly roaming around copypasting staff and switching things on and off  you should first understand the errors you are facing. For example first error: You should lookup on MSDN what `HANDLE` and `HINSTANCE` are and figure out where are you getting them from. You get `hInstance` from `WinMain`. You should lookup on [MSDN for `WinMain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx) and figure out that signature you used is somewhat wrong and you are supposed to use

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
```

So the error with `wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;` assignment of `HANDLE` to `HINSTANCE` should be gone (assuming that I've pointed the correct line of this error because you only specified row).

And so on.

Comment: Thank you a lot. This kind of approach doesn't come naturally for me yet and being given the right direction is very helpful. I originally expected this program to work instantly and therefore thought the problem might not be directly inside the code and more in the configuration of my project or a problem with different versions of my compiler, the windows api, visual studio or something. In addition to that my beginner knowledge of c++ is an obstacle as well. But well, I'm just starting and I appreciate your quick and helpful push in the right direction!